# Starting reputation at 101 vs 1?

Tags: support, reputation, beta

Just wondering why some users start with 101 rep while others start with 1.  Is it to do with activity on Area 51 before the site went to beta?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you associated your account with another account on the Stack Exchange network, you receive a 100+ bonus (for your prior experience) to get your started. The associated account has to have at least 200 reputation to get the bonus.