# Why didn't my 100 reputation bonus get applied?

Tags: support

Obviously this belongs on https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/ instead of here, but I can't ask a question there without a 5 reputation here on https://apple.stackexchange.com/ first!

When I created my account here, I linked it with my other StackExchange accounts (15 others). When I did this upon creating the other SE accounts, I got a +100 reputation bonus, allowing me to upvote/comment/etc.

Why didn't I get that rep bonus here?

I see from [Starting reputation at 101 vs 1?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62/starting-reputation-at-101-vs-1/63#63) that you only get the bonus with a 200 rep on the other sites. While I don't have much rep on most sites, I do have it on StackOverflow.

What's up with this?

Tried to tag this: frustration stackexchange reputation should-be-on-meta

Unfortunately, I don't have the 150 rep required to do that either.

Apparently I need to give it an existing tag now too. Great. SO used to be easy/fun to use. If I had to start over from scratch like this on each SE site, I'd never come back.

Tagging this: settings because nothing is really appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the trouble you're having. I'm not sure why you didn't get the association bonus at first, but it appeared when I unassociated/reassociated your accounts. You now have 101 rep.

Comment: Thanks! I almost tried to "Clear All Associations" but that seemed permanent and it wasn't clear whether I could reassociate the accounts after that. (Plus, if I'd tried that it would hinder someone from looking into the issue.) Thanks again!

Comment: @BJQ glad I could help :-)

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but I'll share this in case it helps fix the issue for someone else. When logging in for the first time to Apple.SE, I left the myOpenID option "Include information from profile:" set to "New Persona" (the default). Every other time I'd associated an account, I'd changed this to "Send no information."